# Microsoft Cognitive - Face API - Using persistedFaceId to Face to Face verification

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

So, I intend to perform a face to face verification using Azure Face Api. In my case, what I need to do is verify if the face in the photo sent by the user is the same as the photo saved in database. My question is: can store faces in a faceList in a way that I can use the **persistedFaceId** for the faces coming from my database instead of performing a detect on the same picture just to get it's Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: can store faces in a faceList in a way that I can use the persistedFaceId for the faces coming from my database instead of performing a detect on the same picture just to get it's Id?

It seems that you'd like to perform face to face verification with a **faceId** of one face that comes from [Face - Detect](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236) and a **persistedFaceId** that comes from a faceList.

Based on my test, currently the [Face - Verify](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523a) does not support this. If we perform face to face verification with a faceId and a persistedFaceId, it would return the follow error in response.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "FaceNotFound",
    "message": "Face is not found."
  }
}
```

And in [Face - Verify](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523a) documentation, we can also find the faceId used in face to face verification should comes from [Face - Detect](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236).

[image]

Comment: Oh well, ok then. Thanks for the clarification