# Azure Cognitive Services - Face API - how do I compare two persistedFaceIds?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I have an Azure Face comparison application that compares two non-persistent `faceIds`.

The following question deals with non-persistent `faceId`s vs `persistedFaceId`s:

[Microsoft Cognitive - Face API - Using persistedFaceId to Face to Face verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55029634/microsoft-cognitive-face-api-using-persistedfaceid-to-face-to-face-verificat)

It's really unclear to me how to compare two `persistedFaceId`s, despite staring at the API reference.

Can I persistently extract `faceAttributes` for two distinct images, then compare the two `persistedFaceId`?

And if so - how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Face Lists was introduced to overcome this limitation.

With Face Lists, you can add multiple FaceIDs to a list which is persisted and use this Face List as a target for the Find-Similar API call. A face list holds a maximum of 1,000 faces. PersistedFaceId represents the added face. No image will be stored. Only the extracted face feature will be stored on server until FaceList - Delete Face or FaceList - Delete is called.

Note persistedFaceId is different from faceId generated by Face - Detect.

To get face information inside faceList use FaceList - Get   (Retrieve a face list’s faceListId, name, userData, recognitionModel and faces in the face list.)

API Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/faceapi/face-list

Announcement: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/cognitive-service-2015-12-21/

Comment: Thanks! I only want to do 1-to-1 not 1-to-many. I am piecing together a workflow from what you are saying - can I draw it somewhere? I'd like to (i) enrol Face A, (ii) enrol Face B, (iii) get a comparison score between the two, which sounds like it is done for a faceId vs a FaceList-enrolled persistedFaceId. It would be using a FaceList of length 1. Does that make sense? Is it possible to get a simple comparison score for two enrolled faceIds? (PS: Can I use UserData to store faceAttribute JSON for example?)

Comment: Is it possible to compare two *persisted*FaceIds? Or can I only do persistent vs non-persistent..?

Comment: you can if you are using both FaceList-enrolled persistedFaceIds